# Rails Ajax form doesn't response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

currently I am using the pg search gem in my application. The search functionality works fine. However, now I want to apply ajax for my form. The thing is after I enter the search query, the form doesn't show any results at all. I dont know where I make mistake. Could you guys please take a real look at my code:

**search.haml**:

```
.row
  %h1.text-center Tìm Giảng Viên
  #teacher_lookup
    = form_tag search_teachers_path, :id => 'custom-search-input', method: :get, class: "input-group col-md-12", role: "search", remote: true do
      .input-group
        = text_field_tag :search,
              params[:search], class: "search-query form-control", placeholder: "Tên giảng viên, ví dụ: Nguyễn Văn A"
        %span.input-group-btn
          = button_tag( :class => "btn btn-danger") do
            .search-size
              %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search

= @teachers.each do |teacher|
  = link_to teacher, school_teacher_url(teacher.school_id, teacher)
  Khoa
  = teacher.department |
  ,
  = link_to teacher.school.name, school_path(teacher.school_id)
  %br/
```

**teachers.js**:

```
var search_teacher;
search_teacher = function () {
   $('#custom-search-input') .on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status) {
      $('#teacher_lookup').replaceWith(data);
      search_teacher();
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  search_teacher();
});
```

Comment: Any error output? You are using standard rails ajax views? So it renders a search_teacher.js.erb?

Comment: @simon.franzen, thank you for your help. So, you meant that the reason my form doesnt work is because I didnt have the search_teacher.js.erb in my view? And it doesn't show any errors. The form just does nothing when I enter the search query.

Answer (score 0):

Better try: 
 - Build an API, which accepts a search param and returns teachers in JSON format.
 - Build a JS function which calls this API with $.getJSON
 - in the getJSON callback you can append the teachers to your HTML

You can still use your form, but you must override the submit functionality with your custom query to the API.

---

other possibility:
Use standard rails ajax and do your stuff inside the views/*/search_teachers.js.erb

---

Here are some code snippets which works without rails built-ins views. Stolen from one of our current projects:

We need a few things: 
 - A rails route
 - a rails controller which makes your search query (to whatever you want) and responses in json format
 - in your frontend we have somewhere a HTML form with a button which triggers a 'load' function
 - the 'load' function makes the ajax call and rerenders your list

```
# routes.rb
get '/my_search_route', to: 'search#query', as: :search_query
```

Then the rails controller to handle the route

```
#app/controllers/search_controller.rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  # method to search after something (e.g. a model named 'Customer')
  def query
    if !params[:q].nil?
      render :json => Customer.where("name ilike :q", q: "#{params[:q]}%") # put this logic into your model
    else
      render :json => [] # not absulutly sure if this is correct syntax
    end
  end
end
```

In your frontend in some of your erb files you have your form. I make a simple example with a input field to make it clear:

```
<!-- app/views/whatever/some_file.html.erb -->
<!-- Input field to search --> 
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />

<!-- HTML list to display your results --> 
<ul id="searchResults"></ul>

<!-- Skript to call the 'load'-function, when user types something --> 
<script>
  $('#search').keyup(function(){
    query = $('#search').val();
    loadData(query);
  });
</script>
```

In your assets you need a javascript file, included in the asset pipeline, where we can store the load function.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/search_functionality.js
// loadData calls the backend
function loadData(query){
  var params = {};
  params['q'] = query;

  // ajax call
  $.get("/my_search_route", params ).done(function( data ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       $("#searchResults").append('<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>');
    }
   });
}
```

This is just an example how to make the roundtrip. In our project, we have a lot more logic inside this stuff, but I think the main part should be clear. Somewhere lies some html and js. With js you can make the ajax call to the server to get the data. The server needs a route and controller which searches after given params. If you have problems use console.log in javascript or puts/debugger on rails side

Comment: What do you mean by building an API? I dont really get it. I searched all the ajax rails video on youtube, and havent yet come across any videos that mention API when using Ajax in rails. Do you have a link or a resource that can help me to understand it?

Comment: I edited my answer and added some basic code snippets. I hope this helps